# Selenium doesn't wait until website has loaded, where to put the codes of your answers?

Tags: testing, selenium, web, ide

in my test case the website needs many seconds until it is loaded, but Selenium doesn't wait for it, although I set it on the slowest option.

I know you will give me now some java codes or something, but I don't know where I have to write down these codes that it works?

I am a newbie, sorry

Thank you

Comment: Please confirm, are you using any programming language or just using selenium IDE. I think you are using IDE only. right?

Answer (score 1):

set implicit or explicit wait as,

after the browser instance insert following line - `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

or just before the element which take time to load place explicit wait as - `WebDriverWait.until(condition-that-finds-the-element)`

For more info [click here](http://assertselenium.com/2013/01/29/webdriver-wait-commands/)

Comment: And where do I have to write this down?

Comment: After you have done your driver.get(), you should preferably use the second statement to wait for an element on the page.  Then you will know that the page is loaded.

Comment: @ Timon Dudaczy write the basic test scripts not export from ide, this will better for you to understand the basics of selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Thread.Sleep(20000);

Where 20000 are the miliseconds. So, 20 seconds.

Hope it helps.